# Como ler o ícone de um app Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, icons

Eu gostaria de saber como pegar as informações do app como ícone, versão, nome, etc., para exibir na tela.

Para versão e nome eu até consegui resolver mas para o ícone não!
Eu sei que poderia criar a referência dela no pubspec e adicionar a pasta android/app/...
Mas não tem uma forma de usar "@mipmap/ic_launcher" direto? Ou algo do tipo?

Esta forma funciona, mas não acho que seja correta!

```
Image(
  image: AssetImage(
    'android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png',
  ),
),
```

A princípio eu preciso só para android.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, seja bem vindo a comunidade Stack Overflow em Português!

Você pode usar o pacote [get_version](https://pub.dev/packages/get_version) para consultar informações sobre o nome da versão do aplicativo, o código da versão, a plataforma e a versão do sistema operacional e o ID do aplicativo no iOS e Android

Adicione isto ao arquivo do seu pacote pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  get_version: ^0.2.2
```

Agora em seu código Dart, você pode usar:

```
import 'package:get_version/get_version.dart';
```

Vá para build.gradle e atualize:

```
defaultConfig {
  versionCode 1
  versionName "1.0"
  minSdkVersion 16
  testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

**Como usar:**

Obtenha a versão do SO:

```
String platformVersion;
// Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
try {
  platformVersion = await GetVersion.platformVersion;
} on PlatformException {
  platformVersion = 'Failed to get platform version.';
}
```

Obter nome da versão:

```
String projectVersion;
// Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
try {
  projectVersion = await GetVersion.projectVersion;
} on PlatformException {
  projectVersion = 'Failed to get project version.';
}
```

Obtenha o código da versão:

```
String projectCode;
// Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
try {
  projectCode = await GetVersion.projectCode;
} on PlatformException {
  projectCode = 'Failed to get build number.';
}
```

Obter ID do aplicativo:

```
String projectAppID;
// Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
try {
  projectAppID = await GetVersion.appID;
} on PlatformException {
  projectAppID = 'Failed to get app ID.';
}
```

Obter nome do aplicativo:

```
String projectName;
// Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
try {
  projectName = await GetVersion.appName;
} on PlatformException {
  projectName = 'Failed to get app name.';
}
```

Demonstração online: https://fluttercommunity.github.io/get_version/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Obrigado João.
E para pegar o ícone da aplicação?
Eu quero exibir um About Dialog e mostrar o ícone da aplicação na caixa de diálogo.